# In PlantUML, how do I specify role names at either end of an association between two classes?

Tags: plantuml

How do I specify role names 'employer' and 'employee' at either end of the association 'employs' between the classes 'Person' and 'Company'? That is, of course, different from the name of the association:[image: 'employs' association between Person and Company classes]

Comment: The pictures shows the correct rendering. Are you looking for the plantuml source code for it?

Comment: @wolfgang-fahl , yes indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@startuml
hide circle
class Person {
}
class Company {
}
Person "+employee 0..*" <-- "+employer 0..1" Company : employs
note on link: [[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/employ employs]] is the name of the association
@enduml
```

[image: rendered]
see also [wiki.bitplan.com](http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/Plantuml#In_PlantUML.2C_how_do_I_specify_role_names_at_either_end_of_an_association_between_two_classes.3F)

try it out at

- http://diagrams.bitplan.com
- see [rendered png image](http://diagrams.bitplan.com/render/png/0xc02a74b6.png)
- see [rendered svg image](http://diagrams.bitplan.com/render/svg/0xc02a74b6.svg)

Comment: Or see the Planuml web service at http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml (resulting in http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/HOyzoiCm341tdq9a_3vYjsle4EW5keSCnb4R4LiAjai9fNTlVj9sazxZWQHKdRAD-Hwywgb3S1ITH-MyJGak69CmFDLh1sS9e-Lf9Rii_Z6CNYP4E6ZzLy2fB7ymBl1OVCCADf4KIqOG1ayyLD0qVSvZgen1rWyQCWdRE6c9DpElPBRiKxSjK8BS8x0D279Tv_b2SMINLjN8tVBK6m00)